# URLDownloadToFile Error(0x80004004) in IDownloadManager::Download

Tags: c++, wininet

I made custom downloader of IE using IDownloader Interface and URLDownloadToFile method.
But **URLDownloadToFile return 0x80004004 error code**.
I wonder! what's wrong in source code?

reference : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/iewebdevelopment/thread/3fbcea06-4e69-4504-82e0-f4786368a5e2

```
STDMETHODIMP CDownloader::Download(IMoniker* pmk,  
        IBindCtx* pbc,  
        DWORD dwBindVerb,  
        LONG grfBINDF,  
        BINDINFO* pBindInfo,  
        LPCOLESTR pszHeaders,  
        LPCOLESTR pszRedir,  
        UINT uiCP )  
{ 
    LPOLESTR sDisplayName; 
    pmk->GetDisplayName(NULL, NULL, &sDisplayName);
    HRESULT hr = URLDownloadToFile(NULL, sDisplayName, L"C:\\downloaded.exe", 0, NULL);
    return S_OK;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it.

COM object on Internet explorer must create file in IE template folder. Because IE protected mode.

Answer (score 2):

This is an error code for E_ABORT, so it looks like your download operation was aborted

From MSDN:

"The download operation can be canceled by returning E_ABORT from any callback"

but since your callback is NULL, it is probably caused by some other problem.

Comment: I found this really useful when I got a 0x80004004 error code from the URL Moniker system, with no idea that it was E_ABORT, thanks!